# Count no. of days in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need query using following data & generate report like end below.

```
text | date
-----------------
aa   | 25-08-2017
aa   | 26-08-2017
aa   | 26-08-2017
aa   | 26-08-2017
aa   | 27-08-2017
ab   | 25-08-2017
ab   | 25-08-2017
bb   | 25-08-2017
bb   | 26-08-2017
bb   | 26-08-2017
bb   | 26-08-2017
```

I need report like,

```
text | days
-----------
aa   | 3
bb   | 2
ab   | 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT` and `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
select `text`, count(distinct `date`) as `days`
from `your_table_name`
group by `text`
order by `days` desc, `text`;
```

Comment: Please, ORDER BY ordinal position was deprecated and removed from the SQL standard decades ago. Do order by column / column alias instead!

Comment: @jarlh : Thank you for your information. I have been updated my answer.

Comment: That's much better!

Comment: @Venkatesh : What you mean?

Comment: I want the text no. of days attended like aa number was attended for 3-days, but its records are 5. So, I need no. of days he attended in the report

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT text, COUNT(distinct date)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY text
```

Comment: I don't think MySQL support cte's. (Not needed anyway...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datediff fnction wich return the difference in days between two date. You have to group by text and make the difference between the min and the max date, so you will have:

```
SELECT text,DATEDIFF(max(date), min(date)) + 1 from mytable group by text;
```

the + 1 is to include the lower extreme 
hope this help